# Click event: switch statement not working

Tags: javascript

I´m trying to trigger multiple click events depending on the var clicked, however the switch statement isn´t working. I think it´s the "var" inside the Switch parameter but I have no idea how to correct it:

```
var buttonQ = document.getElementById('Heater1button');
var buttonW = document.getElementById('Heater2button');
var buttonE = document.getElementById('Heater3button');
var buttonA = document.getElementById('Heater4button');
var buttonS = document.getElementById('Heater6button');
var buttonD = document.getElementById('OpenHHbutton');
var buttonZ = document.getElementById('KicknHat');
var buttonX = document.getElementById("Kickbutton");
var buttonC = document.getElementById('CClosedHHbutton');

$(document).click(function() {
  switch (var) {
    case buttonQ:
      document.getElementById('Q').play(), $("#displaytext").text("Heater 1")
      break;
    case buttonW:
      document.getElementById('W').play(), $("#displaytext").text("Heater 2")
      break;
    case buttonE:
      document.getElementById('E').play(), $("#displaytext").text("Heater 3")
      break;
    case buttonA:
      document.getElementById('A').play(), $("#displaytext").text("Heater 4")
      break;
    case buttonS:
      document.getElementById('S').play(), $("#displaytext").text("Heater 6")
      break;
    case buttonD:
      document.getElementById('D').play(), $("#displaytext").text("Open HH")
      break;

    case buttonZ:
      document.getElementById('Z').play(), $("#displaytext").text("KicknHat")
      break;
    case buttonX:
      document.getElementById('X').play(), $("#displaytext").text("Kick")
      break;
    case buttonC:
      document.getElementById('C').play(), $("#displaytext").text("Closed HH")
      break;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
var id = e.target.id;
  switch (id) {
    case "Heater1button":
      document.getElementById('Q').play(), $("#displaytext").text("Heater 1")
      break;
    case "Heater2button":
      document.getElementById('W').play(), $("#displaytext").text("Heater 2")
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use a `switch` statement, use event listeners attached to each element.

```
buttonQ.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById('Q').play(), $("#displaytext").text("Heater 1");
});
buttonW.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById('W').play(), $("#displaytext").text("Heater 2");
});
```

and so on for all the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, the issue is the `var` inside the switch statement. What variable does this refer to? A switch statement is used to "check the result of *a* and do one of *x*, *y*, etc". In your example I don't see any declaration of a value called "`var`" that the switch is using to evaluate what case to run.

In any event, even if you did have a variable somewhere else in your code called `var`, it won't work because that is a reserved word. You can't name a variable using the word you use to name variables.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How could I make the switch statement evaluate the declared variables and run the intended code?

Comment: @HernanAriel It's unclear what "the intended code" is. Are you trying to execute different code depending on which button the user clicked? Use an event listener, not a switch.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, that´s exactly what I´m trying to do. How would a event listener work in this scenario? Just like the switch?

Answer (score 0):

You are switching on var, which itself does not appear to exist from the code you have provided.  You need to know what was clicked, so you need to use what the jQuery .click() method provides - "this".  Or perhaps in your case you should switch on $(this).attr("id").

See this: https://api.jquery.com/click/